# In order to switch my domain to HTTPS, do I need to change Apache or my Node.js app?

Tags: node.js, apache, ssl, reverse-proxy

I have a web app that runs on my domain. First I had regular HTTP site, which was running on port 8082 on my server, while an Apache server (using virtual hosts) was redirecting requests from port 80 to `localhost:8082`.

Now I got an SSL certificate that I tried to install with my site. I made an HTTPS server in Node, and on `https://localhost:8082` everything worked as it should.

But then I tried serving my domain over HTTPS. I tried editing my virtual host file to use the certificate, but I think I haven't written it correctly. Also, I tried to make it redirect HTTP to HTTPS, but it didn't work.

What should I do? Should I run an HTTP or HTTPS server in Node, and what should I put in my Apache virtual host configuration?

Here's my virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.domain.com
        Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com

        SSLEngine On
        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile "/home/USERNAME/Projects/NODEAPP/chained.pem"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/home/USERNAME/Projects/NODEAPP/domain.key"

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests off

        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        <Location />
                ProxyPass http://localhost:8082/

                ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8082/
        </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: it's unclear to me what you're actually doing, so it's impossible to answer your question. please show us your Apache configuration.

Comment: I edited my question. I am relatively new to this, so I'll try to paraphrase my question. I have nodejs app running on certain port. And I use apache with virtual host to redirect all requests from port 80 to port which my app is using (so that i can run multiple domains at once). Now, i am trying to do to have https nodejs app and i don't know how to set up my config to serve https page, as all i have tried didn't worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Fair warning: my understanding of your question is that you want `https://www.domain.com` to appear in the browser's URL bar, not `https://www.domain.com:8082`. If that's not the case a lot of the below is wrong, but will probably still help you understand your problem better.)

#### Background

(aka, HTTP design crash course because I think you don't quite understand what's going on, but feel free to skip if you do:)

I think you have a misconception as to what Apache's doing - mostly because you're saying that it's "redirecting" requests.

An HTTP redirect is any(?) response with a status code in the 3xx range, and it tells your browser that the resource it's requested has moved somewhere else. For example, let's say that `http://example.com/foo` used to exist, but has since been moved to `http://example.org/bar` (note the `.com` and `.org` difference). If you type in `http://example.com/foo` into your URL bar, your browser will request `/foo` (specifically it will send an HTTP GET request) to `example.com`. `example.com` will then send an HTTP response back to the browser *redirecting* it to `http://example.org/bar`. Then the browser will send an HTTP GET request for `/bar` to `example.org` and get back a response containing the resource.

Here's a diagram:

```
Step 1:

-------------                                   --------------------------
|           |                                   |                        |
|  Browser  | -------- HTTP GET /foo ---------> | example.com web server |
|           | <-- HTTP 301 Moved Permanently -- |                        |
-------------                                   --------------------------

Step 2:

-------------                        --------------------------
|           |                        |                        |
|  Browser  | --- HTTP GET /bar ---> | example.org web server |
|           | <---- HTTP 200 OK ---- |                        |
-------------                        --------------------------
```

Now, here's the thing. That's *not* what you're doing, nor probably what you want to be doing. What you're doing is called reverse proxying, which is where whenever the web server (in your case Apache) receives a request, it just forwards it somewhere else. In your original (all-HTTP) setup, the web browser would request `www.domain.com` from Apache, then Apache would simply forward that request, with little to no modification, to `http://localhost:8082`. Here's the diagram:

```
Step 1:

-------------                        ----------                        ------------------
|           |                        |        |                        |                |
|           | ----- HTTP GET / ----> |        |                        |                |
|  Browser  |                        | Apache | ----- HTTP GET / ----> | localhost:8082 |
|           |                        |        | <---- HTTP 200 OK ---- |                |
|           | <---- HTTP 200 OK ---- |        |                        |                |
-------------                        ----------                        ------------------

Step 2:

There is no step 2. BOOM.
```

The really important thing to note here is that the browser doesn't "see" Node.js, it sees Apache on the other end. Likewise Node.js doesn't "see" the browser, it sees Apache (although typically Apache will augment the request with details about the browser connection - see for example the `X-Forwarded-For` header).

This is an intentional part of the design of HTTP - HTTP request and response semantics don't imply anything about the internal implementation details of how requests are processed. That's why HTTP is so powerful. It lets you create really complex setups - think what you're doing but on a much bigger scale and with even more components - and then abstract over that complication with a simple, uniform interface that's shown to the external world: your URL hierarchy combined with the HTTP request/response cycle.

#### How to solve your actual problem

Now that we've established *what* you're trying to do, here's what your problem is: you're conflating what protocol Node.js is speaking with what protocol Apache is speaking (and thus what the external world is seeing).

Your end goal is for people to connect to your website over HTTPS, right? In that case, you don't need Node.js to speak HTTPS, because the only thing that directly talks to Node.js is Apache. Apache is the thing that speaks to browsers, so Apache is what you need to use HTTPS. Ideally, you'd have Apache speak HTTPS to browsers and HTTP to Node.js - it doesn't matter if Apache encrypts traffic to Node because Node is on localhost. In diagram form:

```
-------------                         ----------                        ------------------
|           |                         |        |                        |                |
|           | ----- HTTPS GET / ----> |        |                        |                |
|  Browser  |                         | Apache | ----- HTTP GET / ----> | localhost:8082 |
|           |                         |        | <---- HTTP 200 OK ---- |                |
|           | <---- HTTPS 200 OK ---- |        |                        |                |
-------------                         ----------                        ------------------
```

So make your Node app listen for HTTP requests, then fix your Apache config to serve stuff with HTTPS, but speak HTTP to the Node backend.

I think what's wrong with your configuration is that you need quotes around the path, i.e. `<Location "/">`. Alternately in the reverse proxy configs that I have, I have `ProxyPass` directives set up without a `<Location>` block, like so:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8082/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8082/
```

so you could try that too.

If it still doesn't work, try removing the `<Proxy>`/`</Proxy>` block - I'm not really sure what that does, but I don't have anything like that in my reverse proxy configurations (which work) - so it might be interfering with something.

As for your HTTP to HTTPS redirect, I don't really see anything wrong with it. Are you sure you're connecting to `www.domain.com` instead of `domain.com`? The second VirtualHost serves both, but the first serves only the former.

Comment: I tried this, but when I restart apache i get following error: `Syntax error on line 19 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain.com.c
Nov 28 13:29:49 myServer apache2[30325]: ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch needs a path when not defined in a location`

Comment: @MihaJamsek wow, yeah. I wrote the end of that answer at ~3AM last night - it's totally wrong. I just edited it; try again. (sorry!)

Comment: @MihaJamsek sure. Remember you can upvote my answer as well as accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

From your description I'm going to summarize your problem as follows:

1. You've configured node.js to accept TLS connections
2. You want Apache to accept TLS connections

OK. So first question. You said:

> I made https server in Node, and on https://localhost:8082 everything worked as it should.

Without changing anything, what happens when you try to access `http://localhost:8082`? I can tell you what happens (no guesses, no "should", I can definitely tell you) but you should at least try it in order to see for yourself what happens.

SPOILERS: HTTP does not support listening for both TLS and unencrypted connections on a single port. It's just the way the protocol was specified. Other protocols like POP3, SMTP, FTP etc have the capability to do this but not HTTP. So what happens is trying to access `http://localhost:8082` will fail.

Now, look carefully at your Apache config:

```
# THIS is the problematic part:
ProxyPass         http://localhost:8082/
ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:8082/
#                   ^
#                   |______ notice this?
```

So the problem is you are proxying to a url that does not work.

You have two options here. Both of them valid depending on how you want to design your architecture.

1. Proxy to `https` instead of `http`.

   ```
   ProxyPass         https://localhost:8082/
   ProxyPassReverse  https://localhost:8082/
   ```

   The advantage of this is that you get end-to-end encryption. Even if someone manage to login to your server they can't listen in to the connection. The disadvantage of this is you're encrypting twice which mean you're using much more CPU time to serve a request.
2. Remove TLS from node.js.

   The advantage of this is that you're letting Apache handle all encryption so your web app does not need to spend any CPU time handling encryption itself. For very large services like Google or Facebook they can even offload the encryption to another front-end server (or more likely servers) so that the server running your web app won't be busy encrypting and decrypting HTTP connections. The disadvantage is that anyone who can login to your server can easily listen in to the connection.

There is a third way that some people do but it's getting less and less popular. Run node.js listening on two ports. For example, configure one to listen to 8082 for http and also listen to 8084 for https then you can proxy http pages to 8082 and https pages to 8084. However, looking at your Apache config I can tell this is not what you want to do.

Comment: fun fact (well, IIRC): there exist RFCs for upgrading HTTP connections to use TLS. the only difference between HTTP and the protocols you mentioned are that HTTP's "upgrade on the same port" mechanism isn't widely used.